# What's the meaning of "in God's name"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> What in God's name have we done?

It seems 'in God's name' = 'on earth'.

Comment: In that context it's a "minced oath".  "In God's name" can of course be used in other contexts where it has a valid liturgical purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without more context, it's probably figurative and used for emphasis.  And yes, you could say that both "on earth" and "in God's name" can be used as intensifiers in this sentence, but I think "on earth" implies more incredulity while "in God's name" is more like regret.

> on earth: *What* is the nature of this thing that we have done?
>
> in God's name: *Why* did we do this (stupid, horrible, some other negative descriptor) thing?

It seems there is a slight difference, but I'm not sure if I've defined it well.

Comment: Agreed - phrases like this seem to hew toward regret and horror: "What in the name of all that is good, decent, and holy, is in this sandwich?" would mean it doesn't taste good, whereas "on Earth" would imply the presence of an unknown ingredient and, possibly, that it's quite delicious.

Comment: That is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 5):

That is merely one kind of *[ejaculation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ejaculation)*:

> a short sudden emotional utterance

It acts as an intensifier for the sentence.

You can see that

> What the hell have we done?

and

> What in God's name have we done?

are considerably more excited, if not stronger, than

> What have we done?